# how to add a new pop-in after click on "Add to Cart"

Tags: popup

i want to add a new pop-in after clicking on "Add To Cart" button which contains the same information and the same design of the usual minicart on the top right , i know there is some tuto like this, but they use the already exist minicart  , but me i want to add new to make my change there and not affect to exist minicart

> can any one help me please ?

i want a new pop up like this to change it as i wich
[image]

Comment: you want modal popup or show simple message ?

Comment: and will display before addtocart or after addtocart? please do mention proper requirement in question

Comment: @GohilRajesh i want to display it after click on "add to cart" , see please the capture above , i want it with all informations and design to make my custom change on it , to not affect the old minicart

Answer (score 0):

> Copy catalog-add-to-cart.js to your theme from
> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

> to
> app/design/frontend/Theme/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

> or override catalog-add-to-cart.js to your custom module.
> Create
> requirejs-config.js file in app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend and
> use the below code.

```
var config =
    {
        map:
        {
           '*':
               {
                'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': 'Vendor_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
               }
        }
    };
```

> Find ajaxSubmit: function and add below code after
> self.enableAddToCartButton(form);

//popup modal code

```
var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-modal-popup"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({
    modalClass: 'add-to-cart-popup',
    title: $.mage.__("Popup Title"),
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Continue Shopping',
            click: function () {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Proceed to Checkout',
            click: function () {
                window.location = window.checkout.checkoutUrl
            }
        }
    ]
});
popup.modal('openModal');
```

//popup modal code

```
var popup = $('<div class="add-to-cart-modal-popup"/>').html($('.page-title span').text() + '<span> has been added to cart.</span>').modal({
    modalClass: 'add-to-cart-popup',
    title: $.mage.__("Popup Title"),
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Continue Shopping',
            click: function () {
                this.closeModal();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Proceed to Checkout',
            click: function () {
                window.location = window.checkout.checkoutUrl
            }
        }
    ]
});
popup.modal('openModal');
```

Pass a popup title as per your requirement.

The popup with “Continue Shopping” and “Proceed to Checkout” button will display

That’s all!

Comment: it's simple popup code. if you want same as minicart you can bind same data in your popup with Knockout or jQuery

Comment: that's what i want really , can you please show me how to do it, to have the same as minicart , i am new on Magento on the same place on window

Comment: You can open minicart too..or you want custom popup only?

Comment: yes open just custom minicart  , it's better than popup